# The this pointer in c++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

what is an equivalence to `return *this` below?

```
#include<cstdlib>
#include<string>
#include"UniversityStaff.h"
using namespace std;
UniversityStaff::UniversityStaff()
{
    name="";
}
UniversityStaff::UniversityStaff(string theName)
{
    name=theName;
}
UniversityStaff::UniversityStaff(const UniversityStaff& theObject)
{
    name=theObject.name;
}
string UniversityStaff::getName()const
{
    return name;
}

UniversityStaff& UniversityStaff::operator=(const UniversityStaff& rtSide)
{
    name=rtSide.name;
    return *this;
}

istream& operator >>(istream& inStream,UniversityStaff& staffObject)
{
     inStream>>staffObject.name;
    return inStream;    
}
ostream& operator <<(ostream& outStream,const UniversityStaff& staffObject)
 {
    outStream<<staffObject.name;
    return outStream;
 }
```

Isn't the this pointer pointing to my Object? Why can't I use " this->name" instead?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you mean `operator==` ? The operator returns a reference to a `UniversityStaff`, returning a string instead would be the wrong type. Where do you want to use `this->name` ?

Comment: Why not use default copy assignment operator?

Answer (score 2):

> Isn't the this pointer pointing to my Object?

It is.

> Why can't I use " this->name" instead?

Because apparently you seek to overload the assignment operator for your own class.  Then it needs to return an object of that class and not something else. Why you decided to overload it, well you tell me.

Please study this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three. If it even makes sense to overload the assignment operator for your class, then you need a destructor and copy constructor too.